# How do i select a database when uploading a file to Ambari when the options have turned blank?

Tags: database, csv, hadoop, hive, ambari

When uploading a csv file from my local pc to Ambari ,after the file has uploaded , I am not able to select a database to create the table in , the options are blank and I can not even write the database name in there , any one experienced this and may have a work around or is this a bug I should log with the dev team
[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: Have you already created a database? What kinds of workarounds are you expecting? E.g `beeline` will allow you to write queries from the CLI

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah , the databases are all there , thing is , this issue is normally happens with large files , like over 500 Meg csv , but sometimes works , I thought it may be a tablespace issue but there is more than enough space,  I have seen a few people online have experienced the same issue and wonder if it's a bug

Comment: I've not used Ambari in several years, but I can imagine that uploading any large file will cause the browser to lag, yes. Particularly, it has to fully upload to the Ambari server, then get sent to HDFS before the UI can fully present anything. I'd suggest using CLI tools (or HUE, even) to create your Hive tables rather than Ambari UI, anyway